# RSS-reader feed updates when app is suspended

Tags: windows-phone-7

So, Ive made Windows Phone app that contains rss-feeds. I would now like to add the possibility for toasts to popup when a stream is updated. Ive read up on how to use Toasts to notify the user, but how can i make my rss-reader periodically poll the rss-feeds for the latests news when the app is suspended in the background. Example code would be highly appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Background Agent Sample" [Windows Phone Code Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Background) to see how you can create a periodic background agent, that will allow you to pool the rss feed(s) and show a toast notification to the user!